# umount of an sshfs volume mounted via fstab results in a zombie file (osxfuse)

Tags: mount

I have installed osxfuse 3.7.1, sshfs 2.10, fuse libs 2.9.7 under High Sierra 10.13.3.

Things seem to work, except that if I mount a distant directory via fstab, upon unmounting the mountpoint is left is left in a zombie state, and the *only* thing I can then do with that path is to reuse it for an sshfs mount, as root. Although there's a weird trick by which I can recover the mountpoint by transfering the zombiness to a different file (see below).

My `/etc/fstab` is:

```
me@host:/home/me  /Users/me/tmp/foo  sshfs  allow_other  0  0
```

This demonstrates the issue (here I’m using `diskutil umount` but `umount` and eject in the Finder’s GUI give the same result):

First, with sshfs directly (no issues):

```
$ cd /Users/me/tmp

$ mkdir foo
$ ls -l
drwxr-x--x  2 me  staff    64B 13 Feb 20:41 foo
$ sshfs me@host:/home/me foo
$ ls foo/
    # OK, contents of the distant directory.
$ diskutil umount foo
Unmount successful for foo
$ ls -l
drwxr-x--x  2 me  staff    64B 13 Feb 20:41 foo
    # umount really worked.
```

Second, via `/etc/fstab` (leads to a zombie file):

```
$ sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
$ echo "me@host:/home/me  $PWD/foo  sshfs  allow_other  0  0" | sudo tee /etc/fstab >/dev/null
$ mount $PWD/foo
$ ls foo/
   #  OK, contents of the distant directory.
$ diskutil umount foo
Unmount successful for foo
```

However, actually now `foo` is "**zombie**":

```
$ ls -l
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root      wheel     1B 13 Feb 21:04 foo
    # (Ownership/timestamp have changed.)
$ sudo chown me:staff foo
chown: foo: No such file or directory
$ sudo ls foo
ls: foo: No such file or directory
$ sudo rm foo
rm: bar: is a directory
$ sudo rmdir foo
rmdir: foo: Resource busy
$ ls /Volumes
Macintosh HD
$ sudo lsof foo
    # Nothing.
```

At this point the mountpoint `foo` has become a zombie file & I almost can't interact with it. Even if I reboot the file is still in its problematic state.

The only thing I can do is to remount it as root:

```
$ mount $PWD/foo
mount_osxfuse: failed to mount /Users/me/tmp/foo@/dev/osxfuse0: Operation not permitted
$ sudo mount $PWD/foo
$ ls foo/
    #  OK, contents of the distant directory.
$ sudo diskutil umount foo
# (Back to the same zombie state.)
```

And I can transfer the zombiness to a different directory:

```
$ mkdir bar
$ ls -l
drwxr-x--x  2 me    staff    64B 13 Feb 21:16 bar
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel     1B 13 Feb 21:12 foo
$ echo "me@host:/home/me  $PWD/bar  sshfs  allow_other  0  0" | sudo tee /etc/fstab >/dev/null
$ mount $PWD/bar
$ ls bar/
    # OK, contents of the distant directory.
$ ls -l -d foo
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel     1B 13 Feb 21:12 foo
$ diskutil umount bar
$ ls -l
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel     1B 13 Feb 21:19 bar
drwxr-x--x  2 me    staff    64B 13 Feb 20:41 foo
    # After umounting bar:
    # foo’s ownerships is me:staff again, bar is zombie.
```

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When `foo` is a "zombie", what is the output, if any, of `sudo lsof foo`? Are there any ssh processes to the remote host running (`ps -ef|grep "me@host"`? There is an alternative fstab entry format that you may want to try: `sshfs#me@host:/home/me  /Users/me/tmp/foo  fuse  allow_other  0  0`.

Comment: @jaume Neither of two searches outputs anything. Changing `/etc/fstab/` to your version causes the mount command to fail because `/Library/Filesystems/fuse.fs/` does not exist. Using `osxfuse` instead of `fuse` in `/etc/fstab` causes the mount command to attempt to use `/Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_osxfuse` which complains that _"This program is not meant to be called directly. The OSXFUSE library calls it."_

Comment: Sorry to read that it didn't solve your problem. I hope someone chimes in with a solution or a helpful hint.